# How to kill all the Tortoise SVN Process in the Windows environment?

Tags: svn, process, kill

From tools like procexp (Sysinternal), we can see and kill various processes who contains the string tortoise or svn. But there are some other running processes that I cannot kill because I do not know their names? I am looking for killing the whole set of SVN processes in the Windows environment?

Comment: Your best bet is to grab the Tortoise SVN sources and study it to find what processes Tortoise SVN spawns.

Comment: taskkill /T ? ..

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of all executables that come with TortoiseSVN 1.7.4:

```
ConnectVPN.exe
SubWCRev.exe
SubWCRevCOM.exe
svn.exe
svnadmin.exe
svndumpfilter.exe
svnlook.exe
svnrdump.exe
svnserve.exe
svnsync.exe
svnversion.exe
TortoiseBlame.exe
TortoiseIDiff.exe
TortoiseMerge.exe
TortoisePlink.exe
TortoiseProc.exe
TortoiseUDiff.exe
TSVNCache.exe
```

Although I find it unlikely that you would have to focus on most of those. Usually you will only see `TortoiseProc` (for commit/update operations) and `TSVNCache`, which keeps track of file states (to display those icon overlays in Explorer).

Why are you even going after TSVN processes? Usually they shouldn't cause any trouble.